# Digitizer turns off when palm is on screen: want to stop this

Tags: touchscreen

I'm working on an algorithm for palm rejection for an Android writing app. The idea is to find features of palm touches versus stylus touches that will allow me to reject the palm touches and keep the stylus touches (without having to use a special stylus) in my app. Unfortunately, my phone won't detect any touches at all when my palm is on the screen. I Googled around about this quite a bit and played with my phone's settings to no avail.

Is this just a hardware thing, or is there some software solution or setting I can change?

My phone: a Galaxy S5. I have also tried this on a number of Samsung tablets.

Comment: Subject might be off-topic for this site but have you looked at Samsung's Pen SDK: http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/samples/20-samples-in-S-Pen-SDK-2-2-5

Comment: I can't use the s pen. Must be a plain stylus.